# Authentication - PLS-00488: 'VALIDATE_USER_FROM_DB' must be a type ORA-06550

Tags: sql, oracle, function, authentication

I'm currently working on an application in Oracle Application Express 5, more specifically I'm trying to create a custom authentication scheme.

I started by creating a function in the SQL command window that would provide my application with a basic level of authentication. I want my users to be able to sign in with their personal student reference number (srn) and date of birth (dob) and this information is taken from the table "student".

```
create or replace function validate_user_from_db 
(p_username in number, p_password in date) 
return boolean 
as v_pw_check varchar2(1); 
begin select 'x' into v_pw_check 
from student 
where upper(srn) = upper(p_username) 
and dob = p_password; apex_util.set_authentication_result(0); 
return true; exception when no_data_found then apex_util.set_authentication_result(4); 
return false; 
end validate_user_from_db;
```

This function compiled with no errors and so I then went on to create a simple query that would test the function.

```
declare
vresult varchar2(10);
begin
if validate_user_from_db ('30134852', '08/17/1997') then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Welcome Back'); 
else
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error');
end if;
end;
```

The query was successful and was outputting "Welcome Back" when the correct credentials were filled. Now that everything was working how I'd hoped I went about creating a new authentication scheme. I named it "User Validation" and set the scheme type to custom.

I've been following a tutorial and researching into authentication schemes and it was suggested that in the PL/SQL code I place the line,

```
return validate_user_from_db;
```

but when I saved and compiled it I got this error message.

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhKYZ.png)

In attempt to try and resolve this issue I decided to write the following function in PL/SQL code window and it compiled without any issues, but when I try run the application and use correct login credentials it just hits me with an error message stating "Invalid Login Credentials".

```
function validate_user_from_db 
(p_username in number, p_password in date) 
return boolean 
as v_pw_check varchar2(1); 
begin select 'x' into v_pw_check 
from student 
where upper(srn) = upper(p_username) 
and dob = p_password; apex_util.set_authentication_result(0); 
return true; exception when no_data_found then apex_util.set_authentication_result(4); 
return false; 
end validate_user_from_db;
```

Any help will be much appreciated as this is my firs time creating authentication with Oracle Apex.

Comment: `return validate_user_from_db;` - you're missing the arguments to your function. Also, you should never rely on implicit string -> date conversions: providing `08/17/1997` as a date input value will fail unless you use American NLS settings. Either use to_char() with an explicit date format, or use the `date` operator which accepts a date in ISO format, e.g. `date '2016-08-17'`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue after messing around with a test application. Turns out a login page is automatically generated depending on the authentication scheme you have set in place. Make sure you delete your existing login page when you change authentication.